# In a trigger, can you test for the value of another property?

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, conditional-statements

Is it possible to base the `value` property of a trigger to a property of an element?

For instance, in a `ControlTemplate` that has a `ScrollBar`, I'm trying to set its `Visibility` property to `Collapsed` if its `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties are equal.

However, the following doesn't work because you can't set a `Binding` as the `Value` of a `Trigger` because a `Trigger` is not a `DependencyObject`.

```
<Trigger Property="Minimum"
    SourceName="PART_ScrollBar"
    Value="{Binding Maximum, SourceName=PART_ScrollBar}">

    <Setter Property="Visibility"
        TargetName="PART_ScrollBar"
        Value="Collapsed" />                                

</Trigger>
```

So can this be done purely with triggers, or do I have to do this in code-behind?

Comment: Any time when `Maximum` and `Minimum` values are the same, you should set `Visibility` to `Collapsed`?

Comment: Yes.  The issue is putting Maximum (or Minimum) in the value test portion of a trigger. I don't think that's possible to do. As illustrated, you can't use a binding and I don't know any other way.  Only thing I can think of is a custom Visibility converter which would be easy, but I'm trying to see if I can do it in the template without code.

Comment: Either have a boolean ViewModel property (`ScrollVisible`?) that is false when `minimum` and `maximum` are equal and true otherwise (although this requires you remembering to call PropertyChanged on `ScrollVisible` when either `minimum` or `maximum` are changed), or use a MultiValueConverter.

Comment: Modifying the ViewModel won't work because I am creating essentially a third-party control that handles custom scrolling so it has no idea about the ViewModel.  Plus, this is layout-related so it wouldn't go in the ViewModel anyway.  I know about using MultiValueConverters but as I said, I was wondering if it could have been done purely in XAML with triggers. Guess not.

Comment: Aaah... I do love when people vote things down with absolutely zero information or comments as to why.  Way to be a good S.O. citizen there, guy (or gal!)

Comment: I love when people vote down a question without any information as to why.  Not exactly good SO behaviors!  At least say *why* they voted it down.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, Id recommend creating a custom behavior

Like this

```
public class MinMaxVisibilityBehavior : Behavior<ScrollBar>
{
    public override void OnAttached()
    {
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor
                .FromProperty(ScrollBar.MaximumProperty, typeof(ScrollBar))
                .AddValueChanged(AssociatedObject, CheckMinMax);
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor
                .FromProperty(ScrollBar.MinimumProperty, typeof(ScrollBar))
                .AddValueChanged(AssociatedObject, CheckMinMax);
    }

    private void CheckMinMax(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       AssociatedObject.Visibility = AssociatedObject.Minimum == 
          AssociatedObject.Maximum ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

and then in your XAML

```
<ScrollBar>
 ........
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <local:MinMaxVisibilityBehavior />
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ScrollBar>
```